# Cannot run web server for the net

Tags: port-forwarding, webserver

I can play Red Alert 2, download/upload torrent files.
But I cannot publish web site, I have installed WAMP. I have a static IP address. But I cannot accees to it over the internet. I think my university is blocking web site servers by looking the packages. Even, I changed my server's port and still there is no access over the internet. What I have to do now to serve to the internet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your university could be doing a number of things. What is likely stopping you is the lack of port forwarding. Since there are probably hundreds of machines in your university's network, the border router doesn't know where to direct HTTP requests. You probably have a local IP corresponding to the university's internal network.

Red Alert 2 and torrents likely work fine due to UPnP and internally initiated connections. If you really have a static external IP, check your firewall. I'd ask the school's network administrator before trying anything though as it may not be allowed by your university.

Answer (score 1):

Playing RA2 and using torrents are applications were your machine will initialise a connection. With torrents, I am guessing that you either had a very slow speed as torrents are good at getting through firewalls - or, your university has NAT/UPnP/something similar.

A webserver on the otherhand simply sits on your machine and waits for incoming connections. You need the firewall/router to forward port 80 (or whatever you want) from the internet into your machine.

If you are on a shared internet, it is unlikely that you will be able to configure this.

You said you have static IP - Is this a static IP on the university network (such as 1922.168.x.x / 10.x.x.x etc.) or a real internet IP (pretty much anything else)?

If it is a university static IP, short of asking he administrator, I think you are out of luck. If it is a real internet IP, do you have your own router in between your machine and the internet? If you do, you need to do port forwarding, if not, it is worth checking your machines firewall that the port is unblocked, however, I fear you may be out of luck.

In any case, if you are paying silly rates for the connection (I know some universities charge a fortune), you should ask the administrator for help.

Comment: The router or whaterver they call it, I don't have it. I know it is one of that big ones and somwhere locked in the dormitory. I just plug a 30 cm ethernet cable from my pc to the wall.

Comment: Removing the firewall didn't helped :/

Comment: Ok, that is a real internet IP and if it is your only one, and as you say - you do not have a router of your own... I would start by checking your local firewall that whatever port the web server is running on is unblocked and failing that, ask the administrator... but, if you have an external real internet IP to your machine, that router really is just routing and not blocking anything.... unless the university has got funky filtering technology.

Comment: Yes, it is my own unique IP address, regisred to me / my pc. I will ask them why I cannot serve server to the net. But I think they have a funky filtering because they are very experienced; this is the university that brougt the Internet to Turkey (18 years ago), and my friend says that he saw in one of their forums a mini tutorial how to track network packages and detedt whatever they want, and at the end saying "do we use it? we will not say it." I'll ask them and post their reply here?

Answer (score 0):

you could be interested in [LogMeIn/Hamachi](https://secure.logmein.com/IT/home.aspx):
I had a similar issue months ago, because I was behind a NAT (precisely inside a MAN="Metropolitan Area Network") and I solved it using that software.
It is free for non-commercial use, so you can give it a try without any problem.

And [here](http://logmeinwiki.com/wiki/Hamachi:Red_Alert_2) you'll find a specific wiki describing how to play Red Alert 2 using LogMeIn/Hamachi: hope that helps.

Regards